# Wait for service function to complete

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a function on my service called processPayment, this function gets the payment details and doing several http calls, transactional stuff and validations. The function is called from a component.
What I couldn't find is, i dont want this function to handle any requests if its still running, lets say the user double clicks or something i want the function to ignore new requests while its running untill completion.
Is this possible? Should i use a service function or a hot subject observable on the service? Maybe use exahustmap?
Whats the best design pattern for that?
Thanks!

Comment: You're going to want to disable whatever triggers the function, so that the user cannot possibly click it again until the request is completed. You can use a simple boolean in your component to achieve that.

Comment: Could you provide more context? e.g: how/when is `processPayment` called from the component; do you need the results from `processPayment`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `exhaustMap`, it will ignore the things, until the child stream has 
been completed.

```js
process = new Subject();

constructor() {
  this.process.pipe(
    // unless the request isn't finished all emits of this.process will be ignored.
    exhaustMap(() => this.http.post()),

    // takeUntil(this.destroy$), // unsubscribe
  ).subscribe(response => {
    // some logic.
  });
}

processPayment() {
  this.process.next();
}
```

Comment: But how do i get a result  from this function?

Comment: add a handler into subscribe for example. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have a component

```
public isCalled = false;
```

//Your Method where you call API

```
public callAPI() {
    if(this.isCalled) {
           return;
    }
    this.isCalled = true;
    this.http.get('url').subscribe(()=>this.isCalled=false;);
}
```

Note :- With Rxjs you will not be able to achieve it..because all the skip operators and other operators work works on continues subscription whose subscription stays alive even after first emit. In your case you are calling a api. It's subscription gets complete for that call and there is no next call in original observable source. each time you click you are making a new subscription.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this is the "old fashioned" way, is there any rxjs way?

Comment: you only want to prevent a double click?

Comment: Thanks guys, please take a look at the solution with rxjs i described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61867393/observable-stops-firing-even-when-catching-the-error   please let me know if that works, its using exahustmap and subject to make sure the handleSeatClick will only handle one request at a time, i dont want to invent the wheel here so is this acceptable way to achieve it?

Comment: in this so,lution you are using you will be having a continous subscription to that subject i believe. please unsubscribe to it in destroy.

Comment: Yes the subject is always subscribed, since the service in singleton i dont think i ever need to unsubscribe,but  what do you think about the overall approach? I am new to angular and rxjs..

Comment: you should unsubscribe in ondestroy of your component. else in future it may lead to memory leaks. in your question above i believed you just wanted to hold a normal http call. I would still say in your case my answer is a simple a better apporach. no continuous observables required. Still you better know what you want to implement exactly.